# How to specify batch (.command) file current location in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, command-line

I have a batch file (.command) that I double click to do work. It has dependencies on files in the same folder, but if I double click the .command file it just launches and assumes the current location is /~

How do I find/specify the location of the .command file in the script itself, so I can refer to relative assets?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using bash (i.e. the script starts with `#!/bin/bash`), you can use $BASH_SOURCE to get the filename of the script.  From that, you can get the directory it's in:

```
mydir="$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")"
```

...and then use that to find files relative to the script, e.g. `cp "$mydir/fileInTheSameFolder" /tmp` (and please always use double-quotes around it, as I did here).

Note that this may be a relative path; for example, if the script was run from an interactive shell with `./scriptname.command`, it'll just come out as ".". This shouldn't be a problem unless the script cd's somewhere else, but if you need the full path you can use this instead:

```
mydir="$(cd "$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")" && pwd)" || {
    echo "Error getting script directory" >&2
    exit 1
}
```

Or, could just `cd` to the script's directory at the beginning of the script:

```
cd "$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")" || {
    echo "Error getting script directory" >&2
    exit 1
}
```

Comment: The path can't be found when directory names contain spaces.

Comment: @StevenVachon It should work as long as you put double-quotes around all references to the path. That is, `ls "$mydir"` and `somecommand >>"$mydir/output.log"` will work, but `ls $mydir` and `somecommand >>$mydir/output.log` will fail. This is one of the reasons it's a good idea to double-quote (almost) all variable references in shell scripts.

Comment: the $BASH_SOURCE is empty in MacOS, but having a value in Linux

Comment: @LCB Are you sure you're running the script under bash, not some other shell?

Comment: @GordonDavisson I got the reason because I am using `oh-my-zsh`. and I didn't know that the line `#!/bin/bash` will be ignored if I run the file with `source ./script.sh`.